# When calculating infinite sums, if and when applicable can you cancel out the variables to equal zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation-method

> When calculating infinite sums, if and when applicable can you cancel out the variables to equal zero?

For example:

if I was trying to solve the infinite sum of this equation:
$$\{x + y + (-x) + (-y)\} + \cdots,$$ where $\{\}$ repeats infinitely, could I use a cancelling out method to cancel out $x$ and $y$ from the equation, and therefore making the sum of the infinite series equal to $0\,$?

Can I do this?

Comment: The definition of an infinite sum is as a limit of the sequence of finite sums. That's the ultimate arbiter of whether a series converges to a value or not. In your case, the sequence of partial sums looks like $\{x,x+y,y,0,x,x+y,y,0,\dots\}$, which doesn't converge (unless $x=y=0$).

Comment: To complement Greg's comment, if the series converges then yes, [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20telescoping%20series,after%20cancellation) are well known and rigorous - *if* you treat them with all due precautions.